# Visual C++ Express 2008 error with MSVCP90D.dll

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-c++-2008-express

When i Try to Build My source code ,it says  MSVCP90D.dll missing. I'd like to know how to correct this

Thanks

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/Vsexpressvc/thread/6c090997-57a6-4b16-a998-22af447cb253

Comment: That's not possible.  Maybe if you try to *run* your code.  Reinstall.

Answer (score 0):

The D in the library name signifies that it's a debug-mode runtime for VC 2008.  Ensure that you haven't made any changes to the debug and release settings of your project, particularly the run-time /MDd in the "code generation" section.

This error would appear when you run your code, not when you build it.  Rebuild the project.